# regex to match the argument of specific functions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, ply

how to write a regular expression to match the below string :

name(abc1) or number(param9) or listget(12jtxgh)

I want to match the string enclosed in brackets only if it is prepended by name or number or listget.

I tried to this : 
r'((.*?))'

and if my expression looks like below :

(name(foo) & number(bar)) - listget(baz)

then it starts matching (name(foo) also. I want my regex to extract only foo, bar and baz from the above expression as it is appended by name, number, listget.

I have to write regex in this form only #r'regex'

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'\b\w+\(([^()]*)\)', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/z0flLh/2)

Comment: As said, i can't use re.findall. I have to write anything between r' ' only

Comment: `appended by` did you mean `prepended by`?

Comment: Excuse me, you have not mentioned such a requirement that you cannot use `re.findall`. Sure, you may use it in `re.finditer` to get all matches. What is your code, BTW?

Comment: yes i mean prepended by sorry, also check the edits. The function name is not like func1 or func2 or func3. I have just given an example. My 3 fucntion names are fixed.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/z0flLh/4

Comment: actually I am working with PLY, that's why i have to use specific format to define regular expressions. So, code is: 

def t_OP(t):
    r'&|-'
    return t

def t_ID(t):
    r'\((.*?)\)'
    return t

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so, as seen above, in all the functions i have first line as some regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regular expression should do the trick:

```
(?:listget|name|number)\(([^)]+)\)
```

You can try a working demo by visiting [this link](https://regex101.com/r/kfAYx2/6). As others pointed out, parenthesis must be escaped in order to match their literal, otherwise they are being used by the regex for different purposes (like capturing groups).

Comment: Actually the parenthesis does not have to be escaped inside the brackets: 9.4.3 ERE Special Characters - "The period, left-bracket, backslash, and left-parenthesis shall be special except when used in a bracket expression ..." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03

Answer (score 0):

In regex brackets are special symbols used for grouping. To match them you have to use an *escape* character `\` like this `\(`.

For NOT matching a symbol ex. brackets:

```
[^)]
```

should be used. Where you don't need the escape character.

For finding an alternative you should use the pipe character `|` surrounded by brackets. Example:

```
 (mary|john)
```

For NOT catching a group in a result match inside the the brackets you should start with `?:`

Comment: but how to check if it is prepended by those 3 function names only?

Comment: can you give the final regex?

Comment: You should be able to do it now but yourself, with the info I&#39;ve written. Paste your example into https://regex101.com/ and see how it is matching. That is how I would have to do it for you.